# Is the effect of a curse in TES Arena permanent?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-arena

In The Elder Scrolls Arena, Curses affects the character stats such as Intelligence, Strength, Luck etc.

I am aware that it can be warded off with the help of a priest, or a potion, or the Cure Curse spell. However, are the effects permanent? Will my stats ever be restored back to normal after the curse has been warded off?

Answer (score 1):

**Once a curse is lifted, its effects are gone**.

From the game's manual:

> A curse is similar to a disease except that it affects your
>   INT, WIL, PER, and LUC. As with all other degenerative attacks, if any
>   of your stats reach zero, you will die. The good thing about curses is
>   that they seldom have a duration long enough to threaten your life.
>   Still, having your INT down to 15 isn’t helpful, nor is it safe. If
>   you are hit with another curse it could kill you. Follow the steps you
>   would if inflicted with a disease and you should be able to ward off a
>   curse or banish it at a temple.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://tes.riotpixels.com/arena/files/arena-manual.pdf)</sup>